# Rails 3.1 asset pipeline doesn't pick up changes to @import'd sheets

Tags: import, sass, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I use `@import`'d partial sheets to organize my css/sass:

```
/app
  /assets
    /stylesheets
      _constants.sass
      _layout.sass
      ...
      app.css.sass

app.css.sass:
  @import _constants.sass
  // basic styles
  @import _layout.sass
  @import ...
```

`app.css.sass` has an `@import` rule for `_layout.sass`, which allows me to share mixins and variables amongst the raw sass files before they're complied down into `app.css`

The problem is that Rails doesn't recognize changes to the `@import`'d partials (`_layout.sass`) and won't regenerate `app.css` until I make a change to the actual `app.css.sass` file itself. This dramatically slows down my workflow and means I have to add/remove blank lines from `app.css.sass` to see changes. Never had this problem in 3.0.

Is there a way of forcing sass assets to regenerate on every server request in development?

Comment: Have you figured this out yet? I've been looking but still can't find a solution.

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet. For further information, I'm using the SASS gem, but not the SASS-RAILS gem. A suggestion was made to try adding the SASS-RAILS gem in too, but this then broke all constants used through the @import link.

Comment: @John you should try again with the latest RC of Rails. There has been some improvements in the asset pipeline in the last couple of them.

Comment: I have the exact same problem in my application as I'm using a similar structure. Also I updated to rc5, but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice these comments come in. Yes, at some point in the last month either Rails 3.1.0 Stable or sass-rails fixed the issue. I can now update any file and see the change immediately, and constants work perfectly. I just found the time to test this out, and it works great in a couple different apps now.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Using a `depend_on` directive may do what you require. This makes the given file a dependency of the base file (so the base file is regenerated when the dependency changes), but doesn't include it in the bundle.

For example:

```
/*
*= depend_on _layout.sass
*= depend_on _constants.sass
*/
@import _layout.sass
@import _constants.sass
```

See this [sass and sprockets blog post](http://rule52.com/2011/06/sass-and-sprockets-for-rails-31/) as well as the [sprockets documentation](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets) (especially the directives section).

Comment: Is this still relevant?  @JohnLein's [comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046495/rails-3-1-asset-pipeline-doesnt-pick-up-changes-to-importd-sheets#comment8970198_7046495) suggests not.

Comment: @AdamSpiers It shouldn't be relevant, as the bug has been fixed a while ago. However, the answer keeps getting up voted, so it is obviously helping some people.

Comment: @DavidMiani I think you're right - I subsequently discovered that it wasn't picking up changes for me because some precompiled assets were getting in the way ... :-/

Comment: I'm using rails 4.0, sass-rails 5.0.1 and for some reason I had the bug and this helped.

Comment: yeah, Im Using Rails 4.1 and less-rails 2.7.1 
And I have the same bug (and the same fix)

Answer (score 2):

The answer from nanothief led me to the solution (thank you!) but in an indirect way. Once I finally found the time to get back on here and look up the referenced post, it had been updated to say that the fix was no longer needed.

Sure enough, it appears that this bug has been fixed in Rails 3.1.0 stable with sass-rails for 3.1.0.  So good! I've confirmed that updating the gems does get everything back to working correctly, tested in a couple of apps.

Comment: a note is that sass can work with rails without sass-rails, by just including haml ... however without sass-rails this issue will bite you

Comment: Well, Im Using Rails 4.1 and less-rails 2.7.1 And I have the same bug (and the same fix).