# How to use twitter bootstrap-sass mixins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Using Rails 3.

Right now in each new `.css.scss` file that I am creating, I want to be able to use the `mixins`, but I just couldn't seem to use it.

Here is my `bootstrap_import.css.scss`:

```
// Import bootstrap
// --------------------------------------------------
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap-responsive";
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .span12, .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
@import "base";
```

When I have another file called `a.css.scss` and I try to `@include border-radius(12px);`, but it just gives this error:

```
Undefined mixin 'border-radius'.
```

**Same goes to `variables`, I would like to change some colors on some variables so that I can use it on any file without needing to include in each CSS file.**

Thank you.

Comment: border-radius is a compass plugin. Are you using compass?

Comment: No, using boostrap-sass mixins. See https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_mixins.scss

Answer (score 3):

Only one import works in my project, probably a bug or a mistake from my side.

My solution with bootstrap-sass v2.0.3.1 to achieve a solution is:
(not 100% what do you expect, I know..)

I create a new scss file like: myAppBase.css.scss

```
/* override bootstrap default variables */
$linkColor:      #FF0000;
$linkColorHover: #000;

@import "bootstrap";

/* App variables */
$bgImage: url('bg.jpg');
$radius: 4px;
$maxHeight:600px;
$minHeight:400px;
$bSize:1px;
```

and if  i need bootstrap and my variables in an other *.css.scss file.
I include this line on the top:

```
@import  "myAppBase";
```

Comment: What if I have multiple CSS files for each controller? With what you are doing with `@import  "myAppBase";`, aren't you duplicating all in `myAppBase` in other CSS files?

Comment: I use one core sass file (like theme 1). In the admin section I have an other core File (like theme 2).in some point I use the sass/css per controller but without the core sass file (without myAppBase). I make only small adjustment for UI controls (exception).

Comment: I found the best way to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138946/proper-scss-asset-structure-in-rails

Answer (score 0):

I followed this guidelines and I was able to fix the error "undefined border-radius". 
https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass