# Why is Bootstrap mixin "button-variant" not being found by rails assets pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Need a second set of eyes. We're getting an error trying to use a bootstrap mixin. Oddly, extends of bootstrap classes are working fine. We're using the latest `bootstrap-sass` gem.

We're getting the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Undefined mixin 'button-variant'.
```

We have the following structure:

In application.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

@import "base/variables";
@import "base/mixins";
@import "base/globals";
```

In globals.css.scss

```
@import "buttons";
```

In buttons.css.scss:

```
.border-btn {
    @include button-variant($color-base, transparent, $color-base);
}
```

Can anyone spot the issue? As far as I can tell, things are setup correctly...

Comment: Try to add import to buttons.css.scss file.

Comment: It works. Can you explain why? Why is the import needed? Also, can you write it up as an answer, so I can check it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add import to buttons.css.scss. I'm not sure exactly why it works so in your case, but I have seen this behavior before. I found following thoughts on the matter: [Proper SCSS Asset Structure in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138946/proper-scss-asset-structure-in-rails), and some workaround here: http://rwilcox.tumblr.com/post/9038701675/sass-variables-and-the-rails-3-1-asset-pipeline

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at the resources.