# appkication.css.scss not loading required files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I am setting up a legacy Rails 3 project, ruby 1.9.3.

The asset pipeline is not working.

My application.css.scss is not really importing it's imports.

Here is my development.rb file:

```
Proj::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.serve_static_assets = false
  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true

  # Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false 
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.debug = true
end
```

and here is my Gemfile

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

#gem 'pg'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
gem "authlogic", "3.0.3"
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'fog'
gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.0"
gem "friendly_id", "~> 3.2.1"
gem 'activemerchant'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'i18n', '0.6.0'
gem 'ajaxful_rating_jquery', :git => "git://github.com/lshemesh/ajaxful_rating_jquery.git"
#gem 'acts_as_state_machine'
gem 'dynamic_form'
gem 'heroku'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'state_machine'
#gem 'bartt-ssl_requirement', :require => 'ssl_requirement'
gem 'faker', '0.3.1'
gem 'populator', '0.2.5'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'daemons'
gem 'rack-ssl-enforcer'
gem 'braintree'
gem 'flag_shih_tzu'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'honeypot-captcha'
gem 'famfamfam_flags_rails'
gem 'language_list'
gem 'simple_captcha2', require: 'simple_captcha'
gem 'haml'
gem 'haml-rails'

# group :development do
#   gem 'thin'
# end

group :production do
  gem 'unicorn'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails', require: false
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem 'factory_girl'
  # gem 'autotest-rails'
  gem 'factis'
  gem 'email_spec'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'
end
```

I have the following on my application.rb

```
config.assets.enabled = true
```

And this is my application.css.scss

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= require famfamfam-flags
*/
```

But require_tree doesn't work.

If I go to the browser and check my application.css file I see the contents of it (the requires statements), instead of an empty file which imported other files.

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the sass import method instead of the tree?  `@import 'famfamfam-flags'`  - wicked name btw.

Comment: Hey U need to use `@import` as u r using .scss, pls check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138946/proper-scss-asset-structure-in-rails

Comment: Yes, that works, but shouldn't the other option work as well?

Comment: It should, but you have `config.assets.compile = false` which (as far as I remember) tells application not to do so.